# How can I get a list of map.graphics?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, graphics

Is there any way I can get a list of all the graphics currently on the map? I was thinking that there would be something along the same lines as adding a graphic to a map such as `map.graphics.getGraphics()`. I am using the ArcGIS API for javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your instance of `map` does not have additional GraphicsLayers added,   `map.graphics.graphics` would return an array of all the graphics currently in the map. If you have added GraphicsLayers, you'd have to loop through each of those as well.

[ArcGIS JS API - Map graphics](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#graphics)